# "You are viewing master, but debug target was deployed from master" error

Tags: google-cloud-debugger

Trying to test GCE Debugger for Golang, followed steps in [official](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/setting-up-go-on-compute-engine) [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/debugging), demo app is hosted on Github. App is up and running, but the Debug page in GCE Developer Console shows the following warning:

> You are viewing master, but debug target gcedebug-test-main-master was deployed from master.
>   To debug this deployment, switch to master.

"Switch to master" is a link, which does nothing.

Looks like a bug, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in the developers console, which should have been fixed by now. Please let me know if you still see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have updated the web page and you should not see this bug anymore.  In fact now you can use your own local source files **without upload**, or even type a file:line without viewing source code at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is long gone. Stackdriver Debugger has a completely new UI, which allows you to use source from multiple locations including,
- Local computer without uploading
- Uploaded capture (snapshot) of your source code
- Google Cloud Source Repository
- GitHub
- Bitbucket

Please let me know if this resolves the issues your experiencing.